# How to make a slice from a leading element and an array?

Tags: arrays, rust, slice

This code seems more complex than it needs to be:

```
pub fn new(id_bytes: [u8; 32], ipv4: Ipv4Addr, port: u16) -> Result<RemotePeer, secp256k1::Error> {
    let serialised_pkey: Vec<u8> = [0x02].iter().chain(id_bytes.iter()).map(|x| *x).collect();
    Ok(RemotePeer {
        id: U256::from_le_bytes(id_bytes),
        pkey: PublicKey::from_slice(&serialised_pkey)?,
        ipv4,
        port
    })
}
```

I have the final 32 bytes of a public key, and I need to prepend it with an '0x02' before creating the public key.

Is there a better alternative to:

```
[0x02].iter().chain(id_bytes.iter()).map(|x| *x).collect();
```

I particularly dislike the `.map()` which only exists to silence an error about `&u8` and  `u8` not being the same.

Comment: Well you can replace `id_bytes.iter()).map(|x| *x)` with `id_bytes.into_iter()`, and `[0x02].iter()` with `iter::once (0x02)`, but that's about it.

Comment: Slices impl `Concat` so you can do this: `[&[0x02], &id_bytes[..]].concat();`.

Comment: The `tap` crate allows `let serialised_pkey: = vec![0x02].tap_mut(|v| v.extend(id_bytes));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `.map(|x| *x)` has a shorter version: `.copied()`. However, there's ways to avoid the iterator entirely.

Since you know the length of the array to be 32, you can avoid allocating a `Vec` by using an array of length 33.

```rust
let mut serialised_pkey = [0; 33];
serialised_pkey[0] = 0x02;
serialised_pkey[1..].copy_from_slice(&id_bytes);
```

If you didn't know the length, you could use `Vec::extend_from_slice`.

```rust
let mut serialised_pkey = Vec::with_capacity(id_bytes.len() + 1);
serialised_pkey.push(0x02);
serialised_pkey.extend_from_slice(&id_bytes);
```

If you had control over `PublicKey`, you could write a constructor that takes an implementer of [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html). This is more flexible since it doesn't require all the bytes to be in one slice. Consider using the `Read` and `Write` traits when dealing with sequences of `u8`.

```rust
use std::io::Cursor;
let serialised_pkey = Cursor::new([0x02]).chain(Cursor::new(id_bytes));
let public_key = PublicKey::from_reader(serialised_pkey)?;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I've saved a line by declaring the array to initially be full of 0x02. `let mut serialised_pkey = [0x02; 33];` `serialised_pkey[1..].copy_from_slice(&id_bytes);`